# Allowing multiple URLs for same Post

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

For a specific post, I want to create the illusion of child-posts.

The current post permalink structure is set to `/%year%/%postname%/`. So using this post URL as an example:

`https://example.test/2020/post-slug/`

I would also like the following URLs to render the same Post:

```
https://example.test/2020/post-slug/hello/
https://example.test/2020/post-slug/small-world/
```

My hope was that something like this would suffice (in *functions.php*), where the `Post ID` is `1000`:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^2020/post-slug/([^/]*)/?','index.php?p=1000&path=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

The idea is that I would also pass the additional path information to the post which would be picked up in the template for some changes to original post.

When I do this, it loads the intended post but the URL changes back to:

`https://example.test/2020/post-slug/`

...and I wanted the longer one to remain.

(I hard-flush rewrite rules in-between attempts).

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve by creating these illusory child posts? E.g. are these different tabs on that posts page? Or an accordion?

Comment: What's '2020' in your URL? I tried your exact rewrite rule, minus the '2020' part, and it works perfectly for me. Notably if the `p` parameter is a page then a redirect happens, but if it's a post it doesn't, so are you sure you're not testing with p set to the ID of a page instead of a post?

Comment: @mozboz Thanks for looking. Updated my question, but '2020' represents current year `/%year%/%postname%/` and I'm only concerned with posts, not pages.

Comment: @tom-j-nowell Goal is to have a full-content post via normal URL, but allow rendering on a chapter/section level too

Comment: Normally that would be done via `#` e.g. `example.com/story#chapter`, the browser woould then position the viewport over the element with the `id="chapter"`. JS can pick this up too ( see hash bangs and hash routers ). Otherwise those URls would need to have different content or they would face SEO duplication issues. It won't be enough to just make the URL work, canonical addresses and sitemaps would need adjusting too, as well as other things

Comment: @tom-j-nowell Yes. Known consequence. `#` based approach is specifically not wanted.